# Find non trivial Ideal such that the intersection is 0

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I recently found this problem:
Let $P$={$p_n | n\in \mathbb{N}$} be the set of primes, written in ascending order.

Let $A=\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/p_n\mathbb{Z}$ and $I\subseteq A$ the set $I$={$(a_i)\in A | a_i=0 $ except a finite number of indices}.

The problem asked to show that $I$ is an ideal (which I had no trouble proving) and to give an ideal $J\neq ${$0$} such that $I\cap J$={$0$}. If I am not mistaken, this ideal cannot exist, because if we had an element $x\in J, x\neq0$, by properties of ideal, $x \cdot ([1],[0],[0],\ldots)=([x_1],[0],[0],[0],...)$ should belong to $J$. However, this element has all zeroes except the first component, so it belongs to $I$. As $I\cap J$={$0$}, it must be $[x_1]=[0]$. Using this argument for every position, we conclude that $x=0$, which is a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks correct to me (I hope I'm not missing something). By the way, this isn't really a proof by contradiction: you assume $x\in J$ and deduce that $x=0$, which comprises a direct proof that $J=\{0\}$ (well technically a proof that $J\subseteq\{0\}$, but the other containment is trivial).

Comment: Great, thanks!!